# No Voronoi polygons created

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

I want to create the Voronoi diagram from a set of point (see below). When I use the "Voronoi Polygons" tool from QGIS, there is an error :

> File
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\VoronoiPolygons.py",
>   line 128, in processAlgorithm self.tr('There were no polygons
>   created.'))
>   _core.QgsProcessingException: There were no polygons created.

What do you think is the reason for that?

I use QGIS 3.0, and the tool works for other sets of points (random, for example).[image]

Comment: Hi, could you share the coordinates of your points?

Answer (score 4):

Just a guess, but perhaps you have multiple instances of points on top of one another? As a multi-point layer. That would create an error where no voronoi polygons are created.

Also, check out your coordinate systems - perhaps there is a discrepancy there.

Answer (score 0):

Several problems with the QGIS Voronoi tool were fixed in QGIS 3.2.2.
Please try again with the lasted QGIS version.